# Commercial stock printing with LaTeX (prefer memoir, if possible)

Tags: memoir, printing

In paragraph 2 of Section 2.2 of `texdoc memoir`, I quote

> ... with one page per piece of stock. In commercial printing the stock material is much larger with several pages being printed on each stock piece; the stock is then folded, cut and trimmed to form the final pages for binding. The class assumes that desktop publishing is the norm.

Is it possible to configure `memoir` to output large stock, multi-page per sheet PDF's, like in commercial printing?

If it is not possible to use `memoir` for this, my solution chain would be:

1. Use `memoir` ordinarily, with `\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}`, among other options.
2. Output single-page per sheet PDF.
3. Use another tool to output the desired large stock, multi-page per sheet PDF. What tool is best for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best tool here, following your alternative solution chain, would be the [`pdfpages` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) in conjunction with the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) as layout support. Here is an example:

1. Assume your original document `mydoc.tex` is typeset in the `memoir` documentclass. Don't use the `showtrims` documentclass option, since page frames will be added by the `pdfpages` packages<sup>1</sup>. Let's hypothetically say the document is typeset on US letter paper (`8.5in` by `11in` using the `letterpaper` documentclass option).
2. Compile `mydoc.tex` to produce `mydoc.pdf`.
3. Create a new file called `final.tex` that looks like this:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
   \usepackage[paperwidth=20in,paperheight=12in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
   \pagestyle{empty}% No page headers/footers
   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x1,frame,delta=2cm 0,noautoscale]{mydoc}
   \end{document}
   ```

   This includes all pages from `mydoc.pdf` (using `pages=-`), adds a frame/border around each page for trimming (using `frame`), puts 2 pages on one sheet (using `nup=2x1`), adds a gap of `2cm` horizontally between each imported page (using `delta=2cm 0`) and does not scale the included pages (using `noautoscale`). Also, the final sheet is set to `20in` by `12in` using `geometry` to replicate your "commercial stock".

   [image]

   If using LaTeX for creating the second document is not your thing, then could use a command-line approach with a tool like `pdfnup`. It forms part of the [PDFjam software package](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam). As you will see, `pdfnup` (or PDFjam) uses the `pdfpages` package to create its output.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could use the `memoir` documentclass option `showtrims` if you already have printing margins included in your document. However, this depends on the eventual output of your document.

Comment: Excellent starting point. Specifically, I'm looking for the ability to have 4 pages per "cutout". I know I'm not using the right publishing terms. For example, one cutout has page 1 on recto, page 2 on verso, page 3 on the facing recto, then page 4 on the verso behind page 3. Imagine folding that cutout once and you can navigate it the way I described. In order to have that, I would want to print on two sides of my commercial stock. Can `pdfpages` or PDFjam do that? What are the right search terms so that I can look for them myself in the docs?

Comment: Oh, I see that there is the `delta` option. That somehow answers my question on the distance between facing pages. How about the two-sided printing?

Comment: I haven't used PDFjam myself, but `pdfpages` can do this. Depending on the number of pages in the document you want to include, you could either specify your layout manually, or writing some script. For example, adding all the odd-numbered (or recto) pages, and then all the even-numbered ones (or verso pages), and possibly re-ordering your pages to make sure pages 1 and 3 have 2 and 4 printed on their backs.

Comment: I see. So I've got fine per-page adding capability. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `pdfpages` allows for using `pages=1,3,5,7,9,11,...` to add odd pages, for example. See the [`pdfpages` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)for more information on this (and other) parameters.

Comment: I just realized that "cutout" is known as a folio. The signature option somehow does it. I have yet to try it out on a printer sometime.